# How to study the behavior of this series in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, summation

I need to compute the Von-Neumman entropy of a density matrix in Quantum Mechanics. The density matrix is

$$\rho=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\tanh^{2n-2}r}{2\cosh^2r}\left[\tanh^2r + \dfrac{n}{\cosh^2r}\right]|n\rangle \langle n|$$

where $|n\rangle$ is a basis. The Von-Neumman entropy is computed as

$$S(\rho)=-\operatorname{Tr}\rho \ln \rho.$$

Since the operator is diagonal, we get

$$S(\rho)=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\tanh^{2n-2}r}{2\cosh^2r}\left[\tanh^2r + \dfrac{n}{\cosh^2r}\right]\ln\left[\dfrac{\tanh^{2n-2}r}{2\cosh^2r}\left[\tanh^2r + \dfrac{n}{\cosh^2r}\right]\right].$$

I need to analyze this as a function of $r$. So I wanted to compute this numerically and plot as a function of $r$. So I did as follows:

```
S[r_] := -Sum[((((Tanh[r])^(2 n - 2))/(2 Cosh[r]^2))[Tanh[r]^2 + n/
   Cosh[r]^2])*(Log2[(((Tanh[r])^(2 n - 2))/(2 Cosh[r]^2))[Tanh[r]^2 + n/Cosh[r]^2]]), 
{n, 1, Infinity}]
```

This defines $S(r)$. Next, I've tried to plot this in a certain range:

```
Plot[S[r], {r, 1, 100}]
```

It simply doesn't do anything, and I end up needing to abort the evaluation. Next I've tried plotting instead `N[S[r]]`, but I just got an empty graph.

Next I've tried to compute just a single value:

```
S[1]
```

It just outputs the series. I've tried using `N[S[1]]` it also didn't work.

I've also tried limiting the sum to a finite number of terms (like 10). It also doesn't give anything. The plot is still empty, and when I try to evaluate `N[S[1]]`it just shows all terms in the sum and doesn't sum them.

I'm certain I'm the one who doesn't know how to handle this. It seems clear that *there must be a way to analyse this with Mathematica*.

So how can I plot $S(r)$ in Mathematica? What is the right way to deal with such a sum?

Comment: You used `[...]` for the braces around the $\tanh^2r+\cdots$ part. Those should be `(...)`, as `[...]` always indicates a function call.

Comment: Thanks @LukasLang, now it works! I thought that `[...]` worked as `(...)`.

Comment: Use `NSum` instead of `Sum`.

Comment: What is the range of $ r $? What is its physical meaning?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I shall try it. By the way, the issue was solved by changing the braces. The only issue is that the sum still must be done with a finite (but large) value of N. Anyway, $r$ is what is called the squeeze parameter. For the problem at hand, what actually interests me is the reparametrization $$\tanh r = \exp\left[-\frac{\Omega}{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{R}}\right]$$ where $\Omega$ is a frequency (range $[0,+\infty)$) which is kept constant, and $R$ is the radius of an observer in Schwarzschild spacetime (range $(0,+\infty)$).

Comment: Interesting. FYI, `NSum` has option `Method` and `Sum` has `Regularization`. You can explore and use them if applicable.

Comment: Amplifying on Lukas Lang's comment, see the tutorial on [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html)